# What is this pink aloe called?

Tags: identification

Does anyone know the name of this aloe?  There's no indentification info available other then the photo itself that i found online.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aloe 'Pink Blush' maybe, certainly looks very similar http://www.llifle.com/Encyclopedia/SUCCULENTS/Family/Aloaceae/22534/Aloe_cv._Pink_Blush

Comment: I think you might be right. Thank you for your help.